# I cannot work regular expressions out, i don't know what is a problem

Tags: python, expression, ipv4

I am trying to write a code for finding out if the ipv4 address is correct using regular expressions and I can't seem to work out what's the problem .

```
import re
pattern=re.compile('([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])')
ip=['17.255.16.45','255.255.255.255','0.0.0.0','0.14.255.14','2555.2564.0.3','0.3.255']

for i in range (len(ip)):
    if re.search(pattern,ip[i]):
        print(ip[i],'ok')
    else:
        print(ip[i],"nope")
```

Comment: Check out this regex tester: https://regex101.com/

Comment: This is a brave effort, but I think you may be putting too much load onto regular expressions here. If you want to be strict about the format, I would use regex just to make sure numbers do not start with a zero (except when it's only 0) and then check values are fine in code later (the question is still valid on its own though).

Comment: regexps are cool, and nice to learn - but this is reinveinting the wheel, and a "XY" problem: you need to validate the IP's strings, not to "fix the regexp"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `\.` is included in the alternation, when it should always be included after any of the options before it. You can fix it by just putting those options within a pair of parentheses. Also, it is recommendable to use [raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640) for regular expressions to avoid issues with escaping.

```py
import re
pattern=re.compile(r'(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])')
ip=['17.255.16.45','255.255.255.255','0.0.0.0','0.14.255.14','2555.2564.0.3','0.3.255']

for i in range (len(ip)):
    if re.search(pattern,ip[i]):
        print(ip[i],'ok')
    else:
        print(ip[i],"nope")
```

Output:

```
17.255.16.45 ok
255.255.255.255 ok
0.0.0.0 ok
0.14.255.14 ok
2555.2564.0.3 nope
0.3.255 nope
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know what was going wrong, but as soon as I'd refactored it into
this it seemed to work:

```
import re

ip_num_pat = r"[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]"

pattern = re.compile(r'(?:({0})\.){{3}}({0})'.format(ip_num_pat))
ip_addrs = [
    '17.255.16.45', '255.255.255.255', '0.0.0.0', '0.14.255.14',
    '2555.2564.0.3', '0.3.255']

for ip in ip_addrs:
    if pattern.match(ip):
        print(ip, 'ok')
    else:
        print(ip, 'nope')
```

In general it can be easier to keep track of things like this by breaking them
up into smaller parts. I think probably the last block was wrong.

Also, note that I have changed your code to use **`.match`**, not `.search`.
This is crucial, because otherwise you will match things like `01.2.3.4`.

But, as others have said, a much easier approach would look something like this:

```
ip_addrs = [
    '17.255.16.45', '255.255.255.255', '0.0.0.0', '0.14.255.14',
    '2555.2564.0.3', '0.3.255', '03.1.2.3']

def is_ip(addr):
    try:
        component_strings = addr.split(".")
        if any(i.startswith("0") and i != "0" for i in component_strings):
            raise ValueError("Components cannot start with 0")
        components = [int(i) for i in component_strings]
        if len(components) != 4:
            raise ValueError("Need 4 parts for an IPv4 address")
        if any(not 0 <= i < 256 for i in components):
            raise ValueError("Components should be in range 0, ..., 255")
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

for ip in ip_addrs:
    if is_ip(ip):
        print(ip, 'ok')
    else:
        print(ip, 'nope')
```

Answer (score 0):

While working on the regexp may be interesting for educational purposes, if the intention is to put this into real code, you'd be better by using Python's `ipaddress` module - instead of reinventing the wheel.

It is [part of Python standard library since Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html), and all you need to do to use it is:

```
import ipaddress

# The "for ... in range(len(...))" pattern is not really needed in Python
# the native for can walk your sequence elements:
for address in ip:
    try:
       ipaddress.ip_address(address)
    except ValueError:
       print(address, "Nope")
    else:
       print (adress, "ok")
```

The obvious advantages, beyond subtle bugs in a regular expression are that it can also parse IPv6 addresses (and if those are not wanted, the protocol can easily be checked in the `.version` attribute) - the `ip_address`  call above returns an object that gives, for free, a host of information on the IP, without any extra effort, including but not limited to:

```
 'is_link_local',
 'is_loopback',
 'is_multicast',
 'is_private',
 'is_reserved',
 'is_unspecified',
 'max_prefixlen',
```